# Test cases failed after upgrading spring boot 2.7.11 from 2.6.8 for Redis connection for default configurations

Tags: spring-data-redis

I am getting below error when running test cases after upgrading spring boot 2.6.8 to 2.7.11 for default configuration of RedisMessageListenerContainer
Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool

My Bean configuration:

```
@Bean
    @Primary
    public RedisMessageListenerContainer springSessionRedisMessageListenerContainer(
            @SpringSessionRedisConnectionFactory ObjectProvider<RedisConnectionFactory> springSessionRedisConnectionFactory,
            ObjectProvider<RedisConnectionFactory> redisConnectionFactory,
            @Qualifier("springSessionRedisTaskExecutor") ObjectProvider<Executor> springSessionRedisTaskExecutor,
            @Qualifier("springSessionRedisSubscriptionExecutor") ObjectProvider<Executor> springSessionRedisSubscriptionExecutor,
            CommonSessionProperties sessionProperties,
            ReadOnlyRedisOperationsSessionRepository sessionRepository) {

        if (sessionProperties.isDefaultEventListenersEnabled()) {
            return   redisHttpSessionConfiguration.springSessionRedisMessageListenerContainer(sessionRepository);
        } else {
            RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();

            RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory = springSessionRedisConnectionFactory
                    .getIfAvailable(redisConnectionFactory::getObject);
            container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
            springSessionRedisTaskExecutor.ifAvailable(container::setTaskExecutor);
            springSessionRedisSubscriptionExecutor.ifAvailable(container::setSubscriptionExecutor);

            log.info("Default Redis message event listeners aren't configured");
            return container;
        }
    }
```

And below is my test class:

```
WebApplicationContextRunner contextRunner = new WebApplicationContextRunner()
            .withAllowCircularReferences(true)
            .withConfiguration(AutoConfigurations.of(RedisAutoConfiguration.class, SessionAutoConfiguration.class));


@Test
    public void shouldDefaultEventListenersBeInitializedWhenEnabledPropertyIsTrue() {
        contextRunner.withPropertyValues(SESSION_DEFAULT_EVENT_LISTENERS_ENABLED + "=" + Boolean.TRUE)
                .run(context -> {
                   
                    assertThat(context).hasSingleBean(RedisMessageListenerContainer.class);
                  assertThat(context.getEnvironment().getProperty(SESSION_DEFAULT_EVENT_LISTENERS_ENABLED))
                            .isEqualTo(Boolean.TRUE.toString());
    }
```

The test case will set the session_defult_event_listerner_enable property to true so that default RedisMessageListenerContainer bean will be created.

If the property is set to false, it correctly creates custom RedisMessageListenerContainer.

Same exception is thrown in 2.6.8 but was handled in code itself.

Any inputs will be valuable.